# Shopping Cart Rules slowing down Cart and Checkout Pages in Magento 1.6.x.x!

Tags: checkout

We have around 30-35 shopping cart rules created in our Magento store. These are making the cart and checkout pages too slow (~10-30 seconds). As soon as I remove all rules, the problem is resolved.

Anyway to get this fixed?

NOTE: I have tried using cache like Redis and APC already which are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem earlier this month. Our client's production server had been running for several months uninterrupted and a restart of apache and php-fpm processes did the trick. I tried re-indexing first but that didn't work.

Comment: No. I have tried clearing all cache. Tried re-indexing. Even tried a completely new server with fresh new versions of all components - PHP, Nginx, PerconaDB but problem remains :(